# Should I keep discovery and validation samples separated also for subanalysis and stratification?

Tags: machine-learning, sample-size, validation, stratification

I am conducting an analysis on RNAseq data on two populations sampled from different geographical regions. I used population A as discovery (about 120 samples and 150 matched controls) and population B as validation (about 100 samples and 100 matched controls) to find differentially expressed genes in cases vs controls and to build machine learning predictive models.

Cases can be further stratified according to clinical characteristics (i.e. disease severity, current therapy, organ involvement); this of course reduces the sample size in each population or produces unbalanced datasets. For instance, in population A we may have 20 cases with "active disease" and 100 cases with "remission", while in population B we may have 30 "active" and 70 "remission" cases. Here is the question:

-Would you keep the two populations separate and apply the same discovery-validation strategy albeit with a reduced sample size?

OR

-Would you merge the two populations increasing the overall sample size reporting the results as "exploratory"?

Comment: Are you asking about merging the two populations just for the stratified analysis? Also, if you are building ML predictive models in this stage, how are you going to select the training and validation data?

Comment: See [this post](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/) for why you probably shouldn't be doing train/test splits on such a small data set. Internal validation of the modeling approach by repeated resampling is a more efficient use of the data and more likely to give results that extend to new samples.

Comment: EdM, according to the suggested post, a fair solution would be to merge the two population and use internal validation methods (bootstrap or repeated 10-fold CV) to validate the model. This also answers Lynn's question.

Comment: Is the solution true when applied to inferential (conventional) statistics? That is, for instance, instead of performing a t-test between "active" and "remission" patients in each population (significant results in both would be regarded as "replicated"), run a GLM incorporating the geographical region as factor?

Answer (score 0):

You might "merge the two populations increasing the overall sample size" and then validate the modeling approach by resampling.

Unless you have tens of thousands of samples, data splitting limits the number of observations contributing to the model and provides test sets that are too small for robust model validation. Frank Harrell summarizes the issues nicely [here](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/).

Including the geographic location as a predictor would allow for systematic differences in baseline expression levels between locations. Further including an interaction of geographic location with disease status in the model would allow the associations of expression levels with disease to differ between the two locations. Either type of result--no differences between locations, or differences between locations--could be informative. The combined model could let you tailor your predictions to the geographic location, if necessary.

Including clinical characteristics in the model allows you to account for them, too, without  the problems of ending up with small subsets that you note. It's often wise to include as many predictors as you can without overfitting the data, to try to avoid the problems of [omitted-variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias).